# Probability that a larger random subset contains a smaller random subset.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> Let $A$ be a subset of $\{1,..,n\}$ such that $|A| = k$ and let $B$ be another random subset of $\{1,..,n\}$ such that $|B| = t < k$.
> What is the probability that $A$ contains $B$? (both $A$ and $B$ are chosen uniformly)

I need to show that this probability is $\Theta\left(\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^t\right)$. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $\binom{n}{t}$ ways to choose a $B$, and there $\binom{k}{t}$ ways to choose a $B$ that is a subset of any given $A$. Thus:

$$P(B\subset A) = \frac{\binom{k}{t}}{\binom{n}{t}} = \frac{\frac{k!}{t!(k-t)!}}{\frac{n!}{t!(n-t)!}} = \frac{k!(n-t)!}{n!(k-t)!} = \overbrace{\underbrace{\frac{k(k-1)(k-2)...(k-t + 1)}{n(n-1)(n-2)...(n-t + 1)}}_{t\text{ factors}}}^{t\text{ factors}}$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Well this is what I came up with as well, but don't I have to consider the sampling of A? that there are N choose K ways to choose A?

Comment: @crommy Each $A$ gives the same probability, so when you average over the $A$s you get the same answer

Comment: @Henry So here is where I am a bit confused, how would this average be calculated? There are N choose K ways to choose A but each one is chosen at the inverse ratio so they cancel out?

Comment: So you have ${n \choose k}$ equally likely cases where the probability is equal to $\frac{\binom{k}{t}}{\binom{n}{t}}$.  So the overall probability is $\frac{1}{{n \choose k}} {n \choose k} \frac{\binom{k}{t}}{\binom{n}{t}}=\frac{\binom{k}{t}}{\binom{n}{t}}$

Comment: The full probability, including different choices of $A$, is $\frac{\binom{k}{t}\binom{n}{k}}{\binom{n}{t}\binom{n}{k}}$. The numerator counts the possible number of ways to choose a $B$ and $A$ that satisfy the conditions of the problem ($B\subset A$), and the denominator is the number of ways to choose any pair of $B$ and $A$ (that do not necessarily satisfy the conditions of the problem).

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

- How many sets $B$ are there with $|B|=t$ and $B \subset \{1,2,\cdots,n\}$?
- Given $A$, how many sets $B_A$ are there with $|B_A| =t$ and $B_A \subset A$?